# Vuepress Build and Deploy Github Actions "ELIFECYCLE" error permission denied for 'build vuepress'

Tags: npm, build, github-actions, vuepress

Trying to use the instructions at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-vuepress to build and deploy a basic vuepress app via Github actions. However, it fails in the "Build and Deploy" script throwing out the following error. The project builds fine on my local machine. Any idea how to mitigate this issue?

```
Running 'npm run build'...


> static-site@1.0.0 build /github/workspace
> vuepress build

sh: 1: vuepress: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! static-site@1.0.0 build: `vuepress build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the static-site@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T20_28_37_948Z-debug.log


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has failed to build the solution.

For further information, please visit the Azure Static Web Apps documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/
If you believe this behavior is unexpected, please raise a Github issue at https://github.com/azure/static-web-apps/issues/
Exiting
```

Comment: What content have in file "/github/home/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T20_28_37_948Z-debug.log"?

Comment: Please share your workflow as it's difficult to provide feedback without it. A couple of things could be wrong for this to happen, but what comes to mind is whether you are using "actions/setup-node" or not. Normally the error above happens when you are missing permissions for creating files in the system.